# Static Ip results in no internet connection in CentOS 6.5 (Basic Server)

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, centos, static-ip

I am unable to get an internet connection with my static IP setup.

Here's my relevant files:

**/etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.myserver
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
IPADDR=192.168.1.44
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
ONBOOT=yes
```

**/etc/resolve.conf**

```
search myserver
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

ifconfig shows 192,168.1.44 (just like it should)

route -n shows:

```
Destination       Gateway           genmask                 flag     Metric           Ref    Use    Iface
192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0            255.255.255.0           U        0                0      0      eth0
169.254.0.0      0.0.0.0            255.255.0.0             U        1002             0      0      eth0
0.0.0.0          192.168.1.1        0.0.0.0.                UG       0                0      0      eth0
```

When I ping the gateway I get:

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.44 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.44 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.44 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

When I ping google, it just hangs until finally saying unknown host.

What's wrong?

Comment: Does it work with dynamic IP addresses ?  Also, what does arp -an show you ?  The problem is most likely in the physical path between the box and gateway.  (Can you describe your setup a bit better ?)

Comment: @davidgo I set VirtualBox to "BridgedAdapter" and now it works. It was not working with "NAT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In virtualBox, the static ip does not work with a NAT connection. Switching to "Bridged Adapter" fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

You still need to add:

GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=192.168.1.1

to your /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file. It worked for me!

Comment: thanks, this worked for me too. on CentOS 7 in XenServer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Intel PRO/1000 MT Server on a NAT Network (NatNetwork) first using `dhclient` to get a DHCP address, Fiddle with hostname, static IP, host, etc. Reboot.  Test `ifconfig eth0`, `route -n`, `hostname`, `ping`, etc. You should not have to switch to Promiscuous mode, however.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using this bash script.

#!/bin/bash

## << FUNCTION ZONE >>

## ========================= SetStaticIpWithInternetOperative(){ GATEWAYNumber=$(nmcli device show | awk ‘FNR==11 {print $2}’) StaticIPNumber=192.168.1.15 UUID=$(nmcli connection show | awk ‘FNR==2 {print $4}’) printf «$UUID» #read clear nmcli connection modify $UUID ipv4.address $StaticIPNumber/24 ipv4.gateway $GATEWAYNumber & processIDC=$! wait $processIDC /etc/init.d/networking restart & processIDC=$! wait $processIDC

#OPTIONAL, ENABLE ONLY IF YOU WANT TO #RESTART THE OPERATING SYSTEM FOR EXAMPLE #AFTER A SYSTEM INSTALLATION
#CUSTOMIZED AN INTRANET MADE WITH RUGBY #LANGUAGE OR ANY OTHER LANGUAGE… xD
#reboot
}

## ======================

SetStaticIpWithInternetOperative

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).